# VBA code Copy / Paste function doesn't work intermittently

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I have code that loops through files and copies data, pastes it to a master file then clears the copied data.

I'm finding that every so often, the data in a random file ends up cleared, but it hasn't pasted it to the master file.

Below is the relevant section of the code.

```
 'Copy data on "Decisions" sheet to "AllSubmissions" Sheet in other workbook ???
            With wb.Sheets("Decisions")
                lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
                If lastrow > 1 Then
                     total = total + lastrow - 1
                    .Range("A2:I" & lastrow).Copy wsAll.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    .Range("A2:I" & lastrow).Delete
                    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
                Else
                    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                End If
            End With
        End If
        'Get next file name
        myfile = Dir
```

Any ideas what could cause this and if there is any fix I could add in? The fact i'm finding the data gets cleared which comes after the copy part of the code is throwing me, but i'm sure its probably something so simple i'm missing too!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a `On Error Resume Next` in your code?

Comment: The only inaccuracy I could find is the missing dot in an occurrence of `.Rows.count`. Of course, the lower case `count` looks really ugly: try not to borrow variable names from VBA. Why don't you share the rest of the code (at least the preceding)?

Answer (score 0):

what about the amounts of data?
copy paste is not the most efficient way to transfer data and maybe you run into "Memory limitations"...

Try adding

`Application.CutCopyMode = False`
before closing the source workbook which has "Decisions" sheet, - it will clear up the clipboard.

if anything else will not help, instead of copy/paste, - try to assign range values, as it does not take so much memory to process and even works faster:

`wsAll.yourRange = wb.Sheets("Decisions").SourceRange.Value`